# using string trim and toLowerCase methods in a single array map method not works as expected

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I want to do a process to it:

1) split it by '.' and make an array

2) make each word and character to lower case

3) trim the array elements

I know that we can do this by coding each step separately but I want to do this in one line.
But it confused me why I can't do this using `map(s => s.toLowerCase() && s.trim())` only the last method in the map works?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
let trapSt = '  I Was Sent = I Sent. To Earth = To Moon     '
trapSt = trapSt.split(".")
only_LowerCase_Works_Here = trapSt.map(s => s.trim() && s.toLowerCase()); // ??? why only s.toLowerCase() works here???!!!!
only_Trim_Works_Here = trapSt.map(s => s.toLowerCase() && s.trim()); // ??? why only s.trim() works here???!!!!

console.log(only_LowerCase_Works_Here); 
console.log(only_Trim_Works_Here);
```

Comment: strings are immutable. You could chain the methods `s.toLowerCase().trim()` or you could simply use `toLowerCase` on the original string before doing the `split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `toLowerCase` and `trim` don't modify the string in place, they return the string after the modification.

The `&&` isn't the same as:

```js
s.toLowerCase().trim()
```

which is what you want.

Try this:

```js
let trapSt = '  I Was Sent = I Sent. To Earth = To Moon     '
trapSt = trapSt.split(".")
only_LowerCase_Works_Here = trapSt.map(s => s.trim() && s.toLowerCase()); // ??? why only s.toLowerCase() works here???!!!!
only_Trim_Works_Here = trapSt.map(s => s.toLowerCase().trim()); // ??? why only s.trim() works here???!!!!

console.log(only_LowerCase_Works_Here); 
console.log(only_Trim_Works_Here);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... plus one... Actually I'm surprised how it worked... I remember `toLowerCase().trim()` resulted in errors before! that was why I used `&&`...

Comment: Not  a problem, and thanks! If the "string" in question is `null` or `undefined`, you will get errors. Other than that, any valid string should be able to go through `.toLowerCase().trim()`